# SimpleMembership - объект 'Users' уже существует в базе данных

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, права, users, asp.net-web-api

Есть SPA на Asp.net MVC. На локали вроде всё хорошо работало. Залил на хостинг - проблема.

Есть контроллер для работы с `MembershipProvider`. В нём несколько методов, но это не важно.

```
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    public object Get()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Важен - атрибут `InitializeSimpleMembership`. Его описание:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }

    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new ITAInitializer());

            using (var context = new ITAContext())
            {
                if (!context.Database.Exists())
                {
                    ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                }
            }

            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ITAContext", "Users", "ID", "Login", autoCreateTables: true);

            if (!Roles.RoleExists(UserRights.Admin.ToString()))
                Roles.CreateRole(UserRights.Admin.ToString());

            if (!Roles.RoleExists(UserRights.Moderator.ToString()))
                Roles.CreateRole(UserRights.Moderator.ToString());

            if (!Roles.RoleExists(UserRights.User.ToString()))
                Roles.CreateRole(UserRights.User.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Вот таким вот образом он должен инициализироваться. Проблема в том, что при любом запросе к методам контроллера падает ошибка:

> There is already an object named 'Users' in the database.

Если удалить таблицу `Users` руками то первый раз всё срабатывает, создается таблица, а дальше опять по новой... Почему он не использует текущую?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать добавление дефолтных значений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае проблема была в том, что пользователь из под которого работает доступ к базе не имел прав `VIEW DEFINITION` и `ALTER`, как я понял.